# Application freeze after the first data transfer via ble

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing an application that transmits data to a remote device (also designed by me). Bluetooth Low energy is being used. In total, I need to 8 transmissions, the transmissions go one after the other. Each subsequent transfer starts after the onCharacteristicWrite event of the previous one.

The problem is that after the first transfer, the application freezes. In the logs at this point, I can see the following:

```
D / OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0x71e6515eb0
D / ViewRootImpl @ 616c063 [MainActivity]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D / InputEventReceiver: channel '1737a41 com.example.example / com.example.example.MainActivity (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
    channel '1737a41 com.example.example / com.example.example.MainActivity (client)' ~ NativeInputEventReceiver.
D / ViewRootImpl @ c8adac [MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
E / ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent () returned.
```

At this moment, the remote device reports the disconnection of the client with the 0x13 status. (After of conformation first transmission).

After the screen darkens, the application continues its work, in the logs the following:

```
V / InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ce956af nm: com.example.example ic = null
I / InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D / BLUETOOTH: onCharacteristicWrite
```

The app reconnects to the device and transfers another piece of data. The remote device confirms the receipt of the data.

Since the data is time-bound, this is where the transmissions end. Please tell me how can I solve the problem of application freeze?

Samsung smartphone, adding "android: configChanges = "orientation | screenSize"" does not solve the problem.

PS If it matters, then I set the MTU to 500, but I only transmit 496 bytes in each transmission.

My code:

```
ch.dataCharacteristic.setValue(data.get(i));
gatt.writeCharacteristic(gatts.get(i).dataCharacteristic);
```

Comment: Update: when the size of the transmitted packet is the same as the MTU, there is no problem with freezing the application. Is there a way to transmit a packet of an arbitrary size with a constant MTU without filling the remaining space with zeros?

Comment: Did you new a Thread to do it?

Comment: Maybe you could post your code? A new thread is never needed when using Bluetooth gatt since the operations are asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I do not create a new thread for ble. I modified my post by adding code to it

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I must to use:

```
ch.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
```

if the server doesn't send a response to the record.